# flink sql - extract values from a nested array and concat in one go

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am using flink sql for a very complex object INSERT statement within it there is an array:
I already have the array UNNEST using CROSS JOIN in t1...and it is not null (used JSON_STRING on it and got the array as json string).

properties:
[
{
displayName: 'n1',
value: 'value1'
},
{
displayName: 'n2',
value: 'value2'
}
]

I tried the following:
CONCAT(JSON_VALUE(t1.properties,'$.displayName'),';')

my goal to get eventually: "n1;n2" but I get null instead.

Answer (score 0):

found it: lax $.[*].displayName